# eventDrop in Full calendar jquery

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

In the evendrop of fullcalendar plugin, I want the event which is dragged, but if I write the following piece of code, it gives me the event of the position to where it is being dropped but not the position from where it was dragged.

```
eventDrop: function( event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view )
{
    console.log(event)
}
```

For example, Suppose there is an event at 9am 22nd of march and I am dragging it to say 9am 23rd of march. So if I write the above piece I get the event for 23rd of march but I am not sure how do I get the event of 22nd of march.

Please help me out here.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [specification](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/eventDrop/):

> event is an Event Object that **hold the event's information** (**date**,
>   title, etc).
>
> dayDelta **holds the number of days the event was moved** forward (a
>   positive number) or backwards (a negative number).
>
> minuteDelta **holds the number of minutes the event was moved** forward (a
>   positive number) or backwards (a negative number). Only useful for the
>   agenda views. In other views, 0 is passed in.

you have all the information that you need to get the date of the event before dragging

e.g.
event date is now 26th July 2012 14:00:00 dayDelta = 1 & minuteDelta = -60 then original date of the event was 25th July 2010 15:00:00